# Objects are not identified using css selector after creating a new angular project

Tags: angular, protractor

Due to some issues with my previous node.js, I have to remove complete node js and npm and reinstalled from the scratch. I have created a new project folder using angular with command npm install -g @angular/cli and replaced my e2e folder with old project's e2e which has the scripts. Now when I run the project, all elements that are used to find using CSS selector are now not working. If I replace the elementfinder to xpath then its identified. Can you help me what am I missing here. Is there any package that I have not installed related to css.

I have Chromedriver version as 75.0.337
selenium server standalone 3.14.0
NodeJS as 12+
npm 6.9.1

Comment: check your browser auto-upgraded?  Try other version of webdriver.

Comment: When you say webdriver, do you mean chromedriver?

Comment: If you use chrome browser, it's chromedriver. What's your chrome version?  And you can try on firefox too to see this issue only on chrome or other browsers too.

Comment: So the browser is launching but you cannot find the element? Could you provide the error message, some of the rendered html and your Protractor config?

Comment: Actually the issue got fixed. I was using `element.all(by.css(...)).first().click()` and in the application there was a change, that the element I am looking was second item in the list which I was not noticed. Thanks for your suggestions though.